# How to deal with create() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)

Tags: django

Am creating an object like so,
`OrderItem.objects.create(order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                          quantity=quantity,
                                          item=i,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)`

i am getting this error, `create() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)`
 I need help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
oi = OrderItem(shopping_id=_shopping_id(request), quantity=quantity, item=i, created_by=anon_user, modified_by=anon_user)
oi.save()
```

My answer is based on information from this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects